# How does the following equality hold on congruence classes.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm trying to follow a chain of inequalities on a proof relating the congruence class of an element of a ring modulo n to a coset. I really don't understand how $(1)=(2)$ and $(2)=(3)$. Could anyone explain the steps in more detail at a basic level so maybe I can understand why the equality holds.

Thanks.

Edit: It won't let me upload a picture directly so I hosted it elsewhere, if someone could embed it here that would be great.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgLrC.png

Answer (score 1):

From your picture, I take it you are confused how the following equalities hold:
$$\{{}x\in{}R\,:\,x-a\in{}I\}{}$$
$$=\{{}x\in{}R\,:\,x=a+y\text{ for some }y\in{}I\}{}$$
$$=\{{}a+y\,:\,y\in{}I\}{}$$

To see how they went from the first to the second, note that $x-a=y$ for some $y\in{}I$ since $x-a\in{}I$.  All they did was assign a new variable $y$ to $x-a$.  This means $x=y+a$.  To get from the second to the third, observe that since all $x\in{}R$ such that $x-a\in{}I$ can be written as $a+y$ for some $y\in{}I$, then we can just run through all $y\in{}I$ instead of of $x\in{}R$ since each such $x$ will be equal to some $a+y$.